# RF Isolator or Circulator for Commercial Product

Tags: rf, microwave, transceiver

Circulator and specifically isolator are used in microwave system to prevent unmatch load damage the transmitter.

As circulator that I seen are very bulky I'm started to think how commercial product like *WiFi Access point* or *LTE modem* prevent damage from disconnecting antenna from SMA connector? what small footprint SMD part can do this?

I'm suspecting that as the transmitted power is < 30dBm the transceiver IC can bear with the reflection.

Comment: Good question mine is at least -10dBm with 3 antenna.  I rotated one that I though was loose and upstairs WiFi dongle on tower receives -45dB ( vs -70dB in old router).   Turned out to be multi-path errors and had to tune router antenna position.  I suspect they do other protect for OTP to reduce drive level, as they have Tx power level controlled with BER and options.

Comment: I have seen many WiFi boards and looked inside routers and once designed test systems for MOT Sat Phone PA's and LAN's and yet to see any isolators or circulators or directional couplers even at 30dBm output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directional coupler is a much less expensive and can be quite small. The directional coupler can sense reflected power and decrease power output when the mismatch is high.

Another approach is to size the transmitter finals to have maximum ratings much above what's required in the matched load case. For low powers, that can be the more economical choice.

Comment: Directional couplers are very useful for VSWR protection, but they're not useful for RX/TX combination. The coupled port is typically 20 to 60 dB down from the through port, and would degrade your receiver noise figure by that amount.

Comment: @Dave, Hi and thanks for your comment and answer, I think your missing a thing. He said to use directional coupler to sense reflected power (as network analyzer do) and decrease power in the case of mismatch load. In this architecture RX/TX path uses input and through port of coupler which have very little insertion loss and a monitor used on coupling port which as you noted is typically 10 to 60 dB down from the through port.

Comment: You're right, I misread the question. I thought you were asking about the transmitter output damaging the receiver. 
For low power systems, the power reflected back isn't too significant, and the IC's used are designed to cope with the reflected power. Higher power amplifiers can have VSWR monitoring build in, using directional couplers or SWR bridges, so that they can self protect.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually addressed at the system level.

LTE uses either Frequency Division Duplexing (FDD) or Time Division Duplexing (TDD). In FDD, the transmit and receive signals are at different frequencies, and a special filter called a Duplexer is used to combine the two signals to the antenna.

In TDD mode, the radio switches between receive and transmit modes using a Transmit/Receive (T/R) switch, so that either the transmitter or the receiver is connected to the antenna at the same time, but never both.

WiFi is a TDD system, where the radio is either receiving or transmitting, but never both at the same time.